# How the image url is wrriten in java fxml

Tags: java, eclipse, image, javafx, fxml

I am working with fxml file and I don't know how to write a url (path) to an image i have , I tried absolote path and directory path

I get an invalid url errors like >>

```
Feb 08, 2019 5:09:27 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by 
JavaFX runtime of version 10.0.2
null/bars-chart.png
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:64

at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2450)
at back_end.image_main.start(image_main.java:25)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1107)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:688)
at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(JavaFXImageBuilder.java:47)
at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(JavaFXImageBuilder.java:37)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:771)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1099)
... 17 more
Exception running application back_end.image_main
```

my project structure is

```
fxml_image :
           src :
                front_end :
                           >(bars-chart.png)
                           >(main.fxml)
                back_end :
                           >(image_main.java)
```

this block is a part of my (main.fxml) >>

```html
    
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="155.0" layoutY="177.0" style="&#10;" text="Drag components from Library here…" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#9f9f9f" wrapText="false">
          <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
          </font>
            </Label>
                <ImageView fitHeight="349.0" fitWidth="606.0" layoutX="12.0"         layoutY="11.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                   <image>
                      <Image url="@bars-chart.png" />
                   </image>
                </ImageView>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
```

this is the java file (image_main)

```java
    package back_end;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class image_main extends Application  {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args); }
        
        @Override 
        public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException { 
        
        // Create the FXMLLoader 
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); 
        // Path to the FXML File 
        String fxmlDocPath = "src/front_end/main.fxml"; 
        FileInputStream fxmlStream = new FileInputStream(fxmlDocPath);
        // Create the Pane and all Details 
        VBox root = (VBox) loader.load(fxmlStream);
        // Create the Scene 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); 
        // Set the Scene to the Stage 
        stage.setScene(scene); 
        // Set the Title to the Stage 
        stage.setTitle("A FXML Example which includes FXML Files"); 
        // Display the Stage 
        stage.show();
    

    }}
```

Is there another way to load the FXML, How image links are interpreted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paths are resolved using the fxml file's location. If you load the fxml using an `InputStream` as source for the fxml data, `FXMLLoader` is unable to determine the location url.

Specify the location instead:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(new File("src/front_end/main.fxml").toURI().toURL());
VBox root = (VBox) loader.load();
```

Assuming the fxml is a resource, I recomend using `getResource` instead to get the url:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/front_end/main.fxml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you to include the image file in your "src" folder. You should create a new folder with name "res" and make it as source folder (option -> Build path -> Use as source folder). Put your image in the "res" folder. Then do the following changes in the fxml file.

`<Image url="@../bars-chart.png" />`

I hope this will work for you.